# Passing php form validate error message back to submit form

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass an error message from a server side form validator in a function back to the form it was submitted in. The validator is working as it prevents the rest of the code saving it to a database as planned. However I cant get it to pass back to the form to display the error

```
function saveComment(){
    $validate = array();
    $id = isset($_POST["articleId"]) ? $_POST["articleId"] : '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    if ( $_POST['name'] == "" ){
         $validate['errorMessage'] = "Please fill out your name.";
      header( "Location:".HOME_PATH."/.?action=viewArticle&articleId=".$_POST['articleID']."");
    }
```

I' trying to pass it back to this

```
if ( isset( $validate['errorMessage'] ) ) {
    echo $validate['errorMessage'];
}
```

When I remove the `if` on the display function I get the error `unidentified index`

What do I need to do to get the form to display the error message. Do I need to pass the array to the function that handles the display of the article?

**FEEDBACK**

For anyone that may find this useful I used @OliverBS post method pretty much unaltered.

Also thank you to @lethal-guitar as he explanation has helped me understand where I went wrong and the various methods that can be used to solve this problem +1

Comment: @BogdanBurim if you're going to bother commenting make it something useful not an utterly pointless statement

Comment: Hey, if this works just make sure you write how you got it to work so someone else can use the question and you don't forget in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a quick glance try this

**Session way**

Make sure to start the session by doing `session_start();` at the top of the file where saveComment is and the isset checked.

```
function saveComment(){

    $id = isset($_POST["articleId"]) ? $_POST["articleId"] : '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    if ( $_POST['name'] == "" ){
         $_SESSION['errorMessage'] = "Please fill out your name.";
         header( "Location:".HOME_PATH."/.?action=viewArticle&articleId=".$_POST['articleID']."");
    }

if ( isset( $_SESSION['errorMessage'] ) ) {
    echo $_SESSION['errorMessage'];
}
```

or you can try

**POST way**

```
function saveComment(){

        $id = isset($_POST["articleId"]) ? $_POST["articleId"] : '';

        if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

        if ( $_POST['name'] == "" ){
             $error = urlencode('Please fill out your name');
             header( "Location:".HOME_PATH."/.?action=viewArticle&articleId=".$_POST['articleID']. "&error=" . $error);
        }

    if ( isset( $_GET['error'] ) ) {
        echo urldecode($_GET['error']);
    }
```

I have not tested this but you should get the basic idea of what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting a variable `$validate` for your currently executing script. Afterwards, you send a redirect header. This will cause your browser to issue a new request, thus ending the currently executing script and scrapping the variable. The new request will trigger another script invocation, where the variable is not known anymore since it only existed for the duration of the first request.

HTTP is stateless, so every variable you set on the server side will only exist until you finish your current request and respond to the client. What you need is a way to pass this variable to the script handling the second request. There are several ways to do so:

- Pass a GET parameter. You could append something like `"&validationError=" . $validate['errorMessage']` to the URL you're passing to the Location header, and then in the display page access it via `$_GET`.
- Save the validation status in the `$_SESSION`. The PHP manual contains a lot of information about sessions (maybe you're already using them?)
- Restructure your code in a way that you don't redirect on error, but on success.

Some more information on the 3rd proposal: You write one PHP-Script which displays the form **and** handles the form post request. If validation fails, you simply redisplay, and insert the `echo` statement you already have. If it suceeds, you redirect to some success page. This way, the variable will remain accessible, since it's still the same request.

Comment: Good point with passing the error number it could help with shortening the length of the query param.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually understand the problem now and khow to deal with it for future reference

Answer (score 1):

When you do a header location your redirecting the user to a new page. Your going to have to either pass the error in the query string or ideally pass it as a variable in the session.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing this all in one file, i.e. The form and the validation as one file.

Then you can do this:

```
<?php
    //set success to 0
    $success = 0;
    $errormsgs = array();

    //check for post
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        //get the data from the form post and validate it
        $valid = validateFuntion($_POST['data'])
            //the is function will validate the data. If it is not valid, it will add a message to $errormsgs

        //check for errors
        if(!$errormsgs){
            //data validation was successful, do stuff

        }
    }//if validation fails, it will fall out of the this code block and move on
?>


<html>
<body>
<?php
//check for errors
if($errormsgs){
    $content .= '<ul class="errors">';
                    foreach($errormsgs as $error){
                        $content .= "<li>" . $error . "</li>";  
                    }
    $content .= "</ul>";
    echo $content;
}
?>
<form name="name" action="" method="post">
    <input name="name" value="<?= (isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '') ?>" type="text">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting the user to the "error" page with the `header` statement. The problem is, of course, this is a completely new page, there's no state left over, so none of your variables exist any more.

There's two ways to do it, either pass it on the query string (so add &error=...) and parse that in your template, or save it to the session.

Of course, you should really be doing this before your template is presented using a different means, but that's a complete rework of your code.